# Overload ModelMultipleChoiceField __init__ for many to many

Tags: django, django-forms

I have something working but I am sure it's not the best way of doing it because I have duplicated code.
It's a widget to display checkboxes for groups that clients can belong to. A client can belong to multiple groups.

I am sure I have messed up the overloading of the widget somehow.

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'Name', max_length=250, unique=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('ClientGroup', related_name="client")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ClientGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'Name', max_length=250, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django import forms
from models import ClientGroup

class ClientGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientGroup
        fields = ('groups',)

    groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ClientGroup.objects.all(),
                                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                        label='',
                                        required=False)

    def __init__(self, client_id = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if client_id:
            self.fields['groups'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = ClientGroup.objects.all(),
                                        initial=ClientGroup.objects.filter(client = client_id),
                                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                        label='',
                                        required=False)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.groups
```

**views.py**

```
def client(request, pk = 0):
    client={}
    if pk != 0:
        client = Client.objects.get(pk = pk)

    groupsForm = ClientGroupForm(pk)
    context = {'client':client, 'groupsForm': groupsForm}
    return render(request, 'client.html', context)
```

Can anyone show me a better way of coding the forms.py?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace

```
class ClientGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # stuff

    def __init__(self, client_id = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if client_id:
            self.fields['groups'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = ClientGroup.objects.all(),
                                        initial=ClientGroup.objects.filter(client = client_id),
                                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                        label='',
                                        required=False)
```

with

```
class ClientGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # stuff

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.client_id = kwargs.get('client_id', None)
        super(ClientGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if client_id:
            self.fields['groups'].queryset = ClientGroup.objects.filter(client=client_id)
```